# I need to merge date rows to a snapshot month row in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi and thanks for your help! I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

```
 Cust  Date  Opening   Count    Count    Count     Count    Closing
  1    01/1/x   1        0        0         0         0         1
  1    ....     1        0       -1         0         0         0
  1    31/1/x   0        0        0        +1         0         1

  2    05/1/x   0       +1        0         0         0         1
  2    ....     1        0       -1         0         0         0
  2    31/1/x   0        0        0        +1         0         1
```

The table above is an example of what I'm dealing with. This table shows the opening balance, the movement and the closing balance for each day. Yesterdays closing is today's opening and the cols in between are movements, everything is a count.

I need to roll this up to a monthly snapshot table as follows,

```
 Cust   Month  Opening   Count    Count    Count     Count    Closing
  1    1/x      1        0       -1        +1         0         1
  2    1/x      0       +1       -1        +1         0         1
```

I'm doing this on a large table, so it needs to be efficient, basically, I have to get the opening on the first of the month, if customer was added later in the month (not the first) then the opening for that month is 0 otherwise I can take the closing from the previous day as today's opening. The count columns track movements during the day and I know that a column will always have a positive or negative 1. So for movements I can use MIN/MAX and group by.

I'm having trouble finding a clean efficient way of basically merging all the daily rows while taking the opening from the first and closing from the last of the month.

I've tried using ROW_NUMBER() partition by customer, order by date and then taking the lowest row as the opening and the highest as the closing, but this trips up when there is no row for the 1st of the month.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a CASE statement inside of a SUM() aggregation function for the Open and close values.  Something like...

```
SELECT ...
       SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(DATEADD(DAY, -1, MyTable.Date)) != MONTH(MyTable.Date) THEN MyTable.Opening ELSE 0 END ) AS Opening,
       SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(DATEADD(DAY, 1, MyTable.Date)) != MONTH(MyTable.Date) THEN MyTable.Closing ELSE 0 END ) AS Closing
FROM MyTable
....
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Happy to help.  If you would, please "close out" the question by marking this as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need conditional aggregation.  I find your logic a bit hard to follow.  Assuming the values are not negative, you can get the open and closing amounts using the following:

```
select cust, year(date), month(date),
       max(case when day(date) = 1 then open else 0 end) as open,
       max(case when day(dateadd(day, 1 date)) = 1 then close else 0 end) as close
       . . .
from table t
group by cust, year(date), month(date);
```

A relatively simple modification handles negative values, if that is necessary.